# Node.js refuses to return row count of MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, node.js

This is my client side snippet:

```
    var stuff = 'this: ';
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users", function (err, results) {
        stuff += results;
    });
    io.sockets.emit('numrows', 'rows length is ' + stuff);
```

This is my server side snippet:

```
<b id = 'test'></b>
<script>
  socket.on('numrows', function(data) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = data;
  });
</script>
```

The HTML gets changed to 'rows length is this: ', meaning that the function fails to return the number of rows. What am I missing?

Comment: Put the `io.sockets.emit()` call inside the callback function.

Comment: And why are you expecting it to return the row count? `results` is a 2-dimensional array of all the information in the `users` table. If you want the row count, use `results.length`.

Comment: Neither of these solutions worked. Adding .length still returns an empty variable.
When I put it in the callback function, the socket message was not emitted at all - it seems that the function does not activate whatsoever.

Comment: What does `console.log(results.length)` show?

Comment: Absolutely nothing! It seems that the function does not activate at all.

Comment: What about `console.log(err)`?

Comment: Still nothing! Logging into the console outside the query, naturally, outputs as expected. Anything inside the function simply does not execute at all.

Comment: If you do an update or insert query, does the database get changed?

Comment: No. I do not have a database manager for node.js, so I was using that method to check whether the queries work at all. When I started xampp and changed the port inside node.js's connection to mysql to xampp's database's port, the function seems to work as expected and I can see my database updating in phpmyadmin. However, when I change the port to my node.js server's port, it ceases to work. I do not want to develop on node.js with apache on just for mysql, but I also don't want to use mongoDB... I know this deviates from the question, but what would you recommend in this situation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use node.js, so I can't really advise.